# Why does the given condition imply the following random variables are not independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $Y ∼ U[0, 1]$ be uniformly distributed in the interval $[0, 1]$. Define the random variables $X_1, X_2$ as
$$X_1 = sin(2πY )$$
$$X_2 = cos(2πY )$$
Why does the fact that $X_1^2 + X_2^2 = 1$ imply that $X_1$ and $ X_2$ are not independent?

Comment: Well, $P(X_1>0.5|X_2=1)\neq P(X_1>0.5)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Informally, if we know that $X_1$ is small in absolute value, then $X_2$ cannot be small in absolute value.

More formally, let $A$ be the event $|X_1|\le \frac{1}{2}$. A look at the sine curve shows that $\Pr(A)=\frac{1}{3}$.  Similarly, let $B$ be the event $|X_2|\le \frac{1}{2}$. We have $\Pr(B)=\frac{1}{3}$.

But since $X_1^2+X_2^2=1$, the event $A\cap B$ has probability $0$. Thus $\Pr(A\cap B)\ne \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$, and therefore $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent.